# Keeping border even if suppressed in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

So I am creating a calendar report in Crystal Reports and I am suppressing days that do not exist in the month. Though when this happens it leaves an ugly looking blank spot in the report. How do I prevent this from happening? I want to keep the border there that way everything looks nice and even, people don't like ugly reports.

Comment: Post a picture of the report in preview.

Comment: I figured out what my problelm was but I can't post it until 8 hours cause my repuation is too low. Ended up having to use boxes and lines instead of the borders, obvious yet didn't dawn on me.

Comment: You could extend the borders on the sections that are exactly above and below your detail section. That way the border is always the same.

Also if you have answered your question, post it as an answer.

Comment: Had to wait 8 hours sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The file I was using as an example actually did not use borders and it just looked very convincing that it was actually using borders. What they were actually using was boxes and lines. This is what was keeping them from being suppressed when the value was 0 and did not belong in the month. What they did after inserting them, for the vertical ones was extend them to the end of the section in formating. Not too difficult just didn't notice it. Thanks though!